# UserProfile matching query does not exist

Tags: django, django-users, django-errors

I had my project running absolutely until I tried to access the my custom UserProfile object in the account view of allauth. Since then I have any consistently getting this error when I try to access any page of my project.

Can anybody point me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you post the error message here and maybe even some code you think might trigger it?

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured out the problem myself. It was really a very stupid mistake, but I am still putting out the answer out there as it might help some naive user like me... Actually I was using a `middleware` that access the `userprofile` and updates a count. It was running fine because I was accessing the site from admin account and the user profile was already created.

But when I logged out and signed in a user whose profile was not created... This problem came up. The `middleware` was trying to access the `userprofile` on any visiting page of my site as it is a `middleware`.

So what I did was, that I changed my middle ware to access a userprofile only if it has been created.